# Rails - is this safe? taking a URL param to query the DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Does Rails automatically protect against vulnerabilities of doing something like:

Given a URL: http://a.com/?id=3131313131313

then in the rails controller

```
@comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
```

Does Rails auto protect that, or do I need to do some type of validation to protect the app from hackers?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ActiveRecord find will always use `.to_i` to prevent all SQL injection magic.

Rails will also auto-escape stuff in queries like this:

```
Comment.where(["id = ?", params[:id]])
```

But **not** in

```
Comment.where("id = #{params[:id]}")
```

Comment: so should I make all my queries like you have above? Comment.where(["id = ?", params[:id]])
 or is what I have now in the q ok?

Comment: @AnApprentice: The `find` you're using is okay. But (and this is a big but), always use the placeholder format (`["id = ?", params[:id]]`) when you're building little chunks of SQL, using string interpolation (`"id = #{params[:id]}"`) leaves you open to SQL injection unless you have carefully validated everything and even then you should still use placeholders to future-proof your code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It will take your params and sanitize that, if you are worrying about sql injection. But better approach is to use url like `http://a.com/31343231`. It is quite simple to make, but looks better

Comment: Does it also sanitize dynamic find helpers like `find_by_name(params[:id])` or is it better to do a where statement?

Comment: @fl00r is it safe to query database in url? using query string

Comment: like Im using this, is it best idea to query in query string, https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-query